# CSS: How to make an input box stretch to the width of its given absolute position left and right value?

Tags: html, css

I am making a small input bar. The bar has 2 input, each positioned with absolute positioning and set to percentage for responsive display.

```css
.input_one {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  right: 61%;
}

.input_two {
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input_one">
<input type="text" class="input_two">
```

I want the inputs to stretch between their 2 left and right values, but the problem now is that they stay solid width and only take one of the 2 set positions... the input box doesn't stretch like I want it to. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why cant use just width attribute on input fields.You need something to stretch the div from inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Check support calc() for u browser http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

```
.input_one {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  right: 61%;
  width: calc(100% - 5px - 61%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input_two {
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  left: 40%;
  width: calc(100% - 32px - 40%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Wow... beautiful and taught me something new about dynamic css! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they are both still using `position:absolute;`

Input1

```
Left:5px;
Width:61%;
```

This statement will give you a control that has a 5px margin from the left and a 61% width coverage of the whole document since its using `position:absolute;`

Since the first input control covers 61% the second one should cover less, than 40% or else it will be off screen on the right side

Input 2

```
Right:32px;
Width:35%;
```

Comment: This works except there is a button on the end of that row which messes everything up.